# Drag and drop a html table into another application

Tags: c#, html, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm having a problem dragging an html table from my C# winforms application into an external application (Outlook email message) and getting it to render as a table instead of a plain text version of that table. I know that when you copy/paste in the clipboard you have to put the table in [CF_HTML format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649015%28VS.85%29.aspx) but that doesn't seem to help with dragging the table. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: What html table in winforms? Do you mean webforms?

Comment: No, I am generating the html code (as a string) when a user clicks and drags a grid in my application and then sending it as the data parameter of the .DoDragDrop method.

Comment: Are you saying that when you copy and paste it works, but drag and drop doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) supports copying and dragging rows from a ListView to other applications, in both text and HTML versions. To do that, it does something like this:

```
DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
this.CreateTextFormats(dataObject);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);
```

To do drag and drop, the code is virtually the same:

```
DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
this.CreateTextFormats(dataObject);
DragDropEffects effect = this.DoDragDrop(dataObject, DragDropEffects.All);
```

CreateTextFormats() is not complicated:

```
public void CreateTextFormats(DataObject do) {
    string textVersion;
    string htmlVersion;
    // Do the work of making the tab-separated text version and the HTML code
    do.SetData(textVersion);
    do.SetText(ConvertToHtmlFragment(htmlVersion), TextDataFormat.Html);
}
```

Getting the HTML format right took longer:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert the fragment of HTML into the Clipboards HTML format.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>The HTML format is found here http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917.aspx
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="fragment">The HTML to put onto the clipboard. It must be valid HTML!</param>
/// <returns>A string that can be put onto the clipboard and will be recognized as HTML</returns>
private string ConvertToHtmlFragment(string fragment) {
    // Minimal implementation of HTML clipboard format
    string source = "http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx";

    const String MARKER_BLOCK =
        "Version:1.0\r\n" +
        "StartHTML:{0,8}\r\n" +
        "EndHTML:{1,8}\r\n" +
        "StartFragment:{2,8}\r\n" +
        "EndFragment:{3,8}\r\n" +
        "StartSelection:{2,8}\r\n" +
        "EndSelection:{3,8}\r\n" +
        "SourceURL:{4}\r\n" +
        "{5}";

    int prefixLength = String.Format(MARKER_BLOCK, 0, 0, 0, 0, source, "").Length;

    const String DEFAULT_HTML_BODY =
        "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">" +
        "<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY><!--StartFragment-->{0}<!--EndFragment--></BODY></HTML>";

    string html = String.Format(DEFAULT_HTML_BODY, fragment);
    int startFragment = prefixLength + html.IndexOf(fragment);
    int endFragment = startFragment + fragment.Length;

    return String.Format(MARKER_BLOCK, prefixLength, prefixLength + html.Length, startFragment, endFragment, source, html);
}
```

Comment: Great example! One addition though: to copy special characters (e.g. Ä Ö Ü ä ö ü ß) correctly, I've added this line at the beginning of the ConvertToHtmlFragment function:

fragment = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fragment));

(taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649015(v=vs.85).aspx )

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need formatting, simply copy it to the clipboard as tab-delimited text. This way it'll paste as a table in Excel, and presumable most other table-compatible applications.

Comment: I do need the formatting that html offers so delimited tables aren't an option.